# JQuery toggling number and character input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How do I toggle character and numeric input in a textbox?

I have a JQuery function to allows only numbers on input

```
$('.numeric').on('input', function (event) { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

I only apply the class `numeric` in an input box and it will restrict character input.

My problem is this.

I have a select box with countries list

```
<select class="form-control" id="country_select" name="country">
    <option value="44">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="681">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="967">Yemen</option>
    <option value="260">Zambia</option>
    <option value="263">Zimbabwe</option>
 </select>
```

Whenever I select `United Kingdom` I want to remove the character restriction on my input box which has the `numeric` class. I want to allow letters and numbers to be input on the textbox

```
<input placeholder="Zip/Postal Code" class="numeric" id="company_zip" name="company_zip" type="text">
```

I have this Jquery code but it is not working. I tried to remove the `numeric` class to allow letters on the input. but it is not working.

```
$('#country_select').change(function(){
    var zip = $('#company_zip');
    var country = $(this);
    $('#area_code').val($(this).val());

    if (country.val() == 44) {
        zip.removeClass('numeric');
    }else{
        if (!zip.hasClass('numeric')) {
            zip.addClass('numeric');
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it did not worked is because event is already attached to element. removing class will not remove already associated events to element.

You should rather have a check for selected option value under change event of textbox:

```
var country = $('#country_select');
$('.numeric').on('input', function (event) { 
   if(country.val() == 44)
     this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

Comment: @KimCarlo: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your class is removed when on change event is triggered but the behavior that has been already added to input box will remain there until we refresh the page.

One way you can achieve this by including

```
  ` $('.numeric').on('input', function (event) { 
       this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
   }); `
```

when on change event is triggered.